# String Manipulation, replacing words with out .replace syntax in python

Tags: python-3.x

Replace all the spaces with the word mouse and display the new string.

Output: Imouselovemousethis

You can not use string methods in python such as find, replace, count, split, etc… or lists

My code so far:

```
string = input("Please enter a sentence: ")
newString = string
for i in range (len(newString)):
    if (newString[i+1] == " "):
        newString = newString [:i] + "mouse" + newString [i+1:]
print (newString)
```

This works for only some inputs...
If the input is:
`hello world hello world hello world hello world`

the output is :
`hellmousmousmousmousmousmousmousmousmousmousmouse world hello world hello world hello world`

What is wrong with the code that makes the spaces occur in the later stages of the output?... I can't seem to figure it out
Thanks

Comment: Can't we use simple replace() available already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using slicing and indexing for this... it seems like a much more simple solution would just be to iterate over the input string and just construct a new string

```
>>> b = "a e b c d e f g h e"
>>> return_string = str()
>>> for char in b:
...     if char == " ":
...         char = "mouse"
...     return_string += char
...     
>>> return_string
'amouseemousebmousecmousedmouseemousefmousegmousehmousee'
```

To answer your question about what is wrong with your code, your slicing and indexing is incorrect. The first problem is that you're not taking into account that you're morphing your newString as you iterate through it and therefore the index you're iterating over no longer matches what you're modifying (hence you're getting garbage). len() gives you a count before your modifications. Here is a simple example

```
string = "a b c"

for i in range(len(string)):
    string += string
    print(string[i])

print(string)

outputs
a

b

c
a b ca b ca b ca b ca b ca b ca b ca b ca b ca b ca b ca b ca b ca b ca b ca b ca b ca b ca b ca b ca b ca b ca b ca b ca b ca b ca b ca b ca b ca b ca b ca b c
```

Notice above.. the loop only iterates the number of times of the len of the original string.  Since you are replacing 1 character with 5 your index no longer matches.  You're then constructing a string based off invalid indexes. 
There are more problems,  but this is the biggest one.